# Can I use i18next-browser-languageDetector before the (async) initialization of i18next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, i18next-browser-languagedetector

I'm using `i18next` and `i18next-browser-languageDetector` like so:

```
await (i18next
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    resources,

    fallbackLng: process.env.DEV ? 'dev' : DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,

    debug: Boolean(process.env.DEV),

    returnObjects: true,

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },

    detection: {
      // Order and from where user language should be detected:
      order: ['localStorage', 'cookie', 'navigator'],

      // Keys or params to lookup language from:
      lookupLocalStorage: I18N_LANGUAGE_KEY,
      lookupCookie: I18N_COOKIE_KEY,

      // Cache user language on:
      caches: ['localStorage', 'cookie'],

      // Only detect languages that are in the whitelist:
      checkWhitelist: true,
    },
  }));
```

Right now the detection is made during the initialization phase of the `i18next` library, which is async, so if I want to check the language that has been detected (`i18next.language`) I need to wait for that to finish.

The problem is I need to detect the language before `i18next` loads the resources in order to set the `Accept-Language` header in `axios` before any request to the backend is made.

I know I could just read `localStorage`, `cookies` or `navigator` myself, but I'd like to use the functionality that is already built-in in `i18next-browser-languageDetector` if possible.